# Possible to create real arrow via CSS and rotate it?

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a complete arrow using CSS?

This is how I create just the head of the arrow: http://jsfiddle.net/2fsoz6ye/

```
#demo:after {
    content: ' ';
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;

    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #333;
}
```

But I also need the back part of the arrow. Just to look like this:

[image: Arrow]

And after this I want to rotate the CSS-arrow, so I would be able to use it dynamically... i.e. pointing to the top, left, 45°...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2fsoz6ye/2/

```
.container{
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    width:60px; height:40px; background:#ccc; margin:100px auto;}
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    border-left: 40px solid #ccc;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-right:-40px;
}
```